# abstract java enum

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class

I write a library that should rely on enums but the actual enum should be defined by the user of my library.

In the following example the `authorize` method requires parameters of the enum type `Permission`.

```
acl.authorize(userX, Permission.READ, Permission.WRITE)
```

My library should be able to handle arbitrary permissions defined by the library user. But I cannot compile my library without a `Permission` enum. So I would need something like

```
abstract enum Permission
```

in my library. Is there a workaround to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use an interface which the enum would then implement. Something along the lines of

```
public interface PermissionType{}
```

which would be used by e.g. the client to define an enum such as

```
public enum Permission implements PermissionType
[...]
```

Then your API would accept parameters using the `PermissionType` type

Comment: As used in JDK7's "more NIO features". For example: http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: that link is now dead. Long live the new link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I'd suggest.

1. write an annotation - `public @interface Permission`
2. make the user annotate each of his permission enums with that annotation:

   ```
   @Permission
   public enum ConcretePermissionEnum {..}
   ```
3. Make your `authorize` method look like:

   ```
   public boolean authorize(User user, Enum... permissions) {
       for (Enum permission : permissions) {
          if (permission.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Permission.class)){
             // handle the permission
          }
       }
   }
   ```

---

If you want your Permission enums to have some specific methods, or just want a 'marker', then you can make the user enums implement an interface of yours (instead of being annotated):

```
interface PermissionInterface {..}
enum ConcretePermission implements PermissionInterface
```

This will enable a compile-time, rather than a run-time check, as with the annotation approach, with the `authorize` method signature looking like:

```
public boolean authorize(User user, PermissionInterface... permissions)
```

Comment: My library should not know the READ permission. The example shows the usage where the user of my library defines the enum. My library should only know "some element of the Permission enum".